DerivedClass missing from wsdl using SoapCore
Using SoapCore to work with SOAP in my web service. I have this simple code below, and expect to see DerivedClass defined in WSDL. But I don't see it. What should I do?
using SoapCore;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
        builder.Services.AddSoapCore();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ITesting, Testing>();

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { 
            endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<ITesting>("/Testing", 
                new SoapEncoderOptions(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
        });
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
    }
}
public class Testing : ITesting
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment Environment;

    public Testing(IWebHostEnvironment _environment)
    {
        Environment = _environment;
    }

    public BaseClass Test(BaseClass someObj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.org/")]
public interface ITesting
{
    [OperationContract]
    public BaseClass Test(BaseClass someObj);
}

[Serializable]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string DerivedProp { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedClass))]
public class BaseClass
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string BaseProp { get; set; }
}


First of all, due to mising class what error ou are getting? If the SoapCore doesn't automatically include derived classes in the WSDL. in that scenario you can either add the [KnownType] attribute to the base class specifying the derived class or use SoapSerializer.AddKnownType in your code to explicitly include it. Both methods inform SoapCore to include the derived class information in the WSDL, allowing clients to understand objects derived from the base class.

@MdFaridUddinKiron I don't get an error. I am missing the derived class in WSDL. I am using SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer enum value, instead of DataContractSerializer. So I assume that I should use XmlElement and XmlInclude attributes, instead of DataContract and KnownType. Anyway, nothing changes even if I add KnownType next to XmlInclude.

SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer part of code was out of sight, so I added some newlines to get rid of horizontal scrollbar. Should be more readable now.

Have you tried using visual studio build in feature for converting the class from your SOAP output?

DerivedType is missing from WSDL. Other apps can't consume my service properly because DerivedType is missing.

Just read on the github main page that XmlInclude is not supported.
